# The encrypted text deletes the text in the file and overwrites it

Tags: python

This is my code ,
when I try to add 2 passwords , it overwrite the file

```py
import time
import hashlib
from hashlib import sha256
import cryptocode
from cryptocode.myfunctions import decrypt
master_pass_db = "03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4"
def main():
    while True:
        print('''
        -------------------------
        Commands:
        1. add a password
        2. read passwords
        3. quit
        4. delete database
        -------------------------
        ''')
        command = input('Command : ')
        if command == '1':
            password = input('Please Enter The New Password : ')
            username = input('Please Enter The Username :')
            password = f'''
            UserName : {username}
            Password : {password}
            '''
            encoded_password = cryptocode.encrypt(password , master_pass_db)
            with open('Database.txt' , 'w+') as f:
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(encoded_password)
                
        elif command == '2':
            with open('database.txt' , 'r') as f:
                passwords = f.read()
                passwords = cryptocode.decrypt(passwords , master_pass_db)
                print(passwords)
        elif command == '3':
            pass
        elif command == '4':
            pass
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')
#1234

master_pass_input = input("Enter Your Master Password : ").encode()
hashing_input = hashlib.sha256(master_pass_input).hexdigest()
if master_pass_db == hashing_input :
    main()
else:
    print('Wrong Password...')
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()
```

For Example :
Enter Your Master Password : 1234

```
    -------------------------
    Commands:
    1. add a password        
    2. read passwords        
    3. quit
    4. delete database       
    -------------------------
```

Command : 1
Please Enter The New Password : omar
Please Enter The Username :FaceBook

```
    -------------------------
    Commands:
    1. add a password        
    2. read passwords        
    3. quit
    4. delete database       
    -------------------------
```

Command : 1
Please Enter The New Password : boody
Please Enter The Username :Instagram

```
    -------------------------
    Commands:
    1. add a password
    2. read passwords
    3. quit
    4. delete database
    -------------------------
```

Command : 2

```
        UserName : Instagram
        Password : boody


    -------------------------
    Commands:
    1. add a password
    2. read passwords
    3. quit
    4. delete database
    -------------------------
```

that is the terminal ,
i want a way to encrypt multiple text and saving them all ,
Thanks For Reading , I hope you guys help me

Comment: You have not asked a question.  Why do you think the code that is overwriting the file shouldn't?

Comment: i edit it , please check it back

Comment: Why do you think the code that is overwriting the file shouldn't?

Comment: should it overwrite the file ?
i want to save as many passwords as the user likes
not only one password

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are asking the code to overwrite rather than append in the context manager:

```
encoded_password = cryptocode.encrypt(password , master_pass_db)
with open('Database.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(encoded_password)
```

The 'w+' mode tells the context manager that you want to overwrite whatever content was in the file. Rather you should change the context manager so that it reads:

```
with open('Database.txt', 'a+') as f:
```

The 'a+' mode tells the context manager to (1) create the file if it doesn't exist and (2) append to the end of the file if it already exists.